# How to make a header/footer-template for all classes?

Tags: header-footer, packages, document-classes, best-practices

I would like to create many documents that all have the same (and also respectively specific) header and footer, no matter which class they are (all of them probably custom classes).
Also, creating the documents shall be generic in the future, that is also why it would be nice to outsource that code.

Currently, I focused on writing a custom `.sty` file. Is this the right way or do I have to/should I include this in every `.cls` file?
Or is there another way to solve this problem? 
(Tutorial page or example would also be very appreciated as understanding, for example, the `fancyhdr` documentation is pure horror for me.)

[image: Thats about how it should look like]

Comment: I think your title is a little misleading. There are no specific a4-classes. Roughly said, you can nearly set every paper size for every document.

Comment: You should definitely do this with a custom package and *not* patch every single `.cls` file by hand. Your first approach is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is good to know to be on the right way. Title will be changed, too. ("A4-classes"->"classes")

Comment: Nice! :) I'll add a quick answer for completeness.

Comment: A last remark: Maybe add into your title 'a header-footer-template' instead of 'template', so future readers may benefit from your question by finding quicker what they are looking for.

Comment: Related or duplicate? [Creating a class file vs using packages](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/261094)

Comment: The question title is more than confusing.

Comment: Some easier that make a custom packages or classes is jut save a nomal preamble as a normal TeX file, said  `preamble.tex`, then  in the new documents preambles insert just `\input{preamble}` and that is all. No need to know about `\RequirePackage` or  ` \NeedsTeXFormat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're totally on the right track. Normally you would simply write something like:

```
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
<header/footer setup>
...
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

If some part of the preamble (in this case `\usepackage{fancyhdr}<header/footer setup>`) should always be the same you simply abstract it into some file to input, a `.sty` file - like you are alredy targeted.

However, keep in mind that in a package you're advised to use `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage`. The overall look of your package could be:

```
%%`dosyhf.sty'
%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2008/04/05]
\ProvidesPackage{dosyhf}
    [2017/09/12 v1.0 Custom headers and footers for every Dosy document]
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
<header/footer setup>
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `dosyhf.sty'.
```

Your documents would then have the following structure and output identical headers and footers (unless you manually change them again after loading your custom package).

```
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage{dosyhf}
...
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

A final remark (as for the comment by @AlanMunn): You should really load only the required packages in such an abstraction.

For further reading about the topic [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261094/creating-a-class-file-vs-using-packages) is a post that treats it in a much more general way.

Comment: +1 I think it's also important to stress that this sort of package should load *only* the exact packages needed to implement the functionality being offered. It shouldn't load 'all the packages that might come in handy' (as many beginner classes/packages sometimes do.)

Comment: Thanks @AlanMunn! Good idea. I'll add a remark. And i've just spotted your comment to the OP. I will also add a link in my answer as it seems highly relevant.